# Setting the gap of layout

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I usually set the layout like this

```
<s:Group>
   <s:layout>
      <s:VerticalLayout gap="10"/>
   </s:layout>
</s:Group>
```

but not sure how to specify the gap if I want to use `new VerticalLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VerticalLayout constructor does not have any parameters, so you won't be able to do this in-line in MXML as part of the layout property.  You'll have to set the gap property on the layout after creating it.  Perhaps in a creationComplete handler, do something like this:

```
groupID.layout.gap = 10;
```

You can probably even do this in-line:

```
<s:Group layout="{new VerticalLayout()}" id="groupID" creationComplete="{groupID.layout.gap = 10}"></s:Group>
```